# How to pass zsh alias function to pipe

Tags: zsh, git, function

I have a zsh alias:

```
gitbs() {
    git branch | grep -- $1
}
```

And I would like to pass the result into git checkout, for example:
`git checkout | gitbs state`
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell pipe passes the output of a command to the input of another command. This won't help you here: you want to pass the output of a command as a command line argument of another command. The tool for that is [command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution). So the basic idea is

```
git checkout "$(gitbs state)"
```

(It's still a pipe under the hood, but the reader side of the pipe is the shell itself: it reads the output and then constructs a command line including that output.)

However, the output of `gitbs state` is not the right format to pass to `git checkout`: it has extra spaces and sometimes punctuation characters on the same line as the branch name. (Also color formatting codes, but only when the output is a terminal or when git calls a pager automatically, not when the output is a pipe.) Also, if there is no matching branch or more than one, you'll get a somewhat weird error message from `git checkout`.

To fix this, you can change `gitbs` to produce the raw branch name(s) as output. Here's a version that keeps the pretty formatting intended for humans if the output is a terminal, and just prints one branch name per line otherwise. It uses [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) to enumerate branch names. The [conditional expression](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions) `-t 1` tests whether standard output is a terminal.

```
gitbs () {
  if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    git branch
  else
    git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' 'refs/heads/*'
  fi | grep -- "$1"
}
```

With this definition of `gitbs`, `git checkout "$(gitbs state)"` will work.

Note the double quotes around the command substitution. Without double quotes (<strike>`git checkout $(gitbs state)`</strike>), the output is split into separate arguments at whitespace, so if multiple branches match, the resulting command will be something like `git checkout foobar1 foobar2`, which will not check out `foobar1` but instead will overwrite the current version of the file `foobar2` with the version from `foobar1` if a file named `foobar2` exists.

To avoid this pitfall, it may be better to define a different version of `gitbs` which requires a single matching branch. You get the benefit of a clearer error message if there are zero or more than one matching branches, although there's still an extra message about the current branch from `git checkout`. This function puts the list of matching branches in an [array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters)

```
gitbs1 () {
  local branches
  branches=($(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' 'refs/heads/*' | grep "$1"))
  if ((#branches == 0)); then
    echo "No branch contains '$1'" >&2
    return 3
  fi
  if ((#branches > 1)); then
    echo "Multiple branches match '$1':" >&2
    print -lr $branches >&2
    return 3
  fi
  echo $branches
}
```

Then you can safely write `git checkout $(gitbs1 state)`.

---

If you turn on the option [`glob_complete`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBCOMPLETE) (i.e. `setopt glob_complete` in your `.zshrc`), then you can type

```
git branch *foo*Tab
```

and `*foo*` will be replaced by the name of the matching branch if there is one. If there are multiple matching branches, you'll get the same kind of menu or cycling behavior as for ordinary (prefix) completion.

Comment: *the output is split into separate arguments at whitespace* is misleading. It's split on `$IFS` characters, and `$IFS` contains by default SPC, TAB, NL and NUL (3 out of dozens of possible whitespace characters, and 1 non-whitespace character).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True but irrelevant here. The only whitespace that could be present in the git output is spaces and newlines. The function is meant to be used from the command line so a pathological `IFS` containing e.g. letters is not a concern.

Comment: We don't know what `$IFS` may contain in the shell of anyone reading this Q&A. But regardless, stating that it splits on whitespace, when it's not even true in the default case is misleading. I'd rather we describe what happens rather than people getting the idea that `$(...)` splits on whitespace (even if that's true to  some limited extent in some cases).

Comment: This exactly what I wanted, and thanks for the detailed explanation, since I'm using zsh I'll use your second solution as it seems more resilient.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an alias, that's a function.

If you want to pass the words from the output of a command as arguments to another command, that's what command substitution is for:

```
git checkout $(gitbs state)
```

Would capture the output of `gitbs state` (here, whether it's a function, alias, or external command doesn't matter), remove the trailing newline characters, split on characters of `$IFS` and the resulting words passed as separate arguments to `git checkout`¹

To pass only the first word resulting of that splitting:

```
git checkout ${$(gitbs state)[1]}
```

To pass the whole output (minus the trailing newline characters) as *one* argument to `git checkout`, quote it:

```
git checkout "$(gitbs state)"
```

To split on arbitrary strings rather than on `$IFS` characters, use the `s` parameter expansion flag (or `f` to split on line feeds):

```
git checkout ${(f)"$(gitbs state)"}
```

(note that empty elements are removed).

The `xargs` command can be used for that, however note that the splitting is done in `xargs`' very special own way and `xargs` can only run external commands (not shell builtins nor functions).

```
gitbs state | xargs git checkout
```

`xargs` may run `git checkout` several times if `gitbs state`  outputs a large number of words, larger than can fit in one command line.

---

<sup>¹ in other Bourne-like shells, you'd need to disable globbing (`set -o noglob`) to prevent it being performed on the resulting words. That doesn't apply to `zsh` unless in sh/ksh emulation mode</sup>